# Optional tag in the schema

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, tags

How to create an conditional tag, say in the following example,
I want either  or  tag. Both cant be present in the . Only one of them. How can I create a XML schema like this?

```
Ex:
  <tool>
     <tool_name>xyz</tool_name>
  </tool>

  or 

 <tool>
    <tool_file>xyz.xml</tool_file>
 </tool>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an element declaration for element tool, whose type is a complex type called say toolType. This should be a complex type with a content model which is an xs:choice with two children, an xs:element name="tool_name", and an xs:element name="tool_file".

Answer (score 0):

Introduced namespaces to your example (maybe more complex than you want, but good practice):
Schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://example.com/tools"
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/tools"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:element name="tool">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="tool_name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="tool_file" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

This is valid:

```
<tool xmlns="http://example.com/tools">
  <tool_name>hammer</tool_name>
</tool>
```

This is not:

```
<tool xmlns="http://example.com/tools">
  <tool_name>hammer</tool_name>
  <tool_file>hammer.png</tool_file>
</tool>
```